# Ruby Input Array, Output Array without duplicates

Tags: arrays, ruby, duplicates

# creating empty array (array1)

```
 array1 = [] 
    i = 0
```

# taking 10 numbers from user and storing them in the array

```
 while array1.size < 10    
        print "Enter a number: "
        array[i] = gets.chomp.to_i
        i += 1
    end
```

# pushing only the unique elements into a new array (array2)

```
k = 0
j = 0
array2 = []

while k < array1.size
    if array1[k] != array1[j]
        if array2.include? (array1[k])
            puts "Element already exists"
        else
            array2.push(array1[k])
        end
        j += 1
    end
    k += 1
end

puts array2
```

It only works in some situations, but at all times, the first element that is unique is not being added to the new array for some reason, should I be starting j or k at 1, rather than 0?

I know that i can use .uniq and turn the array into a set and then back to an array, or just intersect the array with &, but i wanted to make it without ruby "shortcuts", any advice?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko   damn, i just edited that because i knew the veterans will say something like that, yoiu are quick

Comment: By the way, Array#uniq returns an Array, not a set.
So `array2 = array1.uniq` would do just fine

Answer (score 0):

Sure.
k and j are both equal to 0 at startup.
So array1[k] == array1[j] is true, and you get k+=1.
k is now 1, and you missed the first element of array1.

Nothing specially Rubyish about this solution :

```
array2 = []
array1 = [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6]

i=0
while i<array1.size do
  element = array1[i]
  if !array2.include?(element) then
    array2.push(element)
  end
  i += 1
end

puts array2.inspect
```